# I can't seem to import my csv file and set the strings as factors when importing

Tags: r, csv

For some reason when trying multiple ways I can't seem to import the csv needed and set `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and there is no checkbox like my teacher told me to use when doing it through the import window...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the homework explanation.

While importing, in the import window, change
the name to a shorter name and make sure to check the box “Strings as factors”. <-- this is the homework explanation.

Comment: The "import window" - in what software? RStudio?

Comment: yea, I imported as base and it still is giving me a NULL when trying to check levels()

Comment: I see the checkbox when using From Text (base). You'll need to include some/all of your example data in the question, and the code used to check factor levels, if you want more help.